# Copy and merge columns to new worksheet

Tags: vba

I have a project I am working on for work. It involves 12 columns: Column A is the Country name (country name from A to Z), Column B is the country ID, Column C is the Subscriber count of a particular country. Column D, E and F, is the supplier name, cost, and conversion rate of a specific company called Yonitech. Column H, I and J are also the supplier name, cost and conversion rate of another specific company called Aliworld, Column K,L and M are also the supplier name, cost and conversion rate of the third company called Lanck.

Basically, company Yonitech has supplier options for the countries that they can cover, with the cost and conversion rate listed. Likewise for company Aliworld and Lanck as well.
The supplier names of all 3 companies can be different.

I'm trying to write VBA codes to copy the information to another worksheet, information on the new worksheet would be the country name, country ID, subscriber count, as well as supplier name, cost and conversion rate. So what i'm trying to achieve is to copy paste the supplier names, cost and conversion of Yonitech into the new worksheet, and if cells are blank, it will then look through the supplier options of 2nd company Aliworld and copy paste the supplier names, cost and conversion of Aliworld before it similarly do the same for Lanck also.
So the new worksheet should only have 6 columns - country name, country ID, subscriber count, supplier name, cost and conversion rate, in which the last 3 columns are a combination of supplier options from the three companies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if conditional to look for if cell value is zero, then copy from another company.
It would be easy if you share table or xl file.